# Entity Framework Code First Migration manually removed column causing issue with migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Blog object that has an Admin object. I initially had this setup wrong and it created my columns incorrectly. I manually removed the "Admin_Id" foreign key field and relationship. Now when I run the migration again, it doesn't add the foreign key and relationship back.

Can I force the entity framework somehow to update the database again?

My objects:

Admin

```
public class Admin: WebPage, IWebPage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Blog

```
public class Blog : WebPage, IWebPage
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string ArticleBody { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostingDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Admin Admin { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogCategory BlogCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why did you removed them manually instead of using migration?

Comment: a mistake. how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: I could not figure out how force the code first migrations to handle adding the fields and foreign keys back, however, when I manually added the fields and foreign keys back, it worked properly again. 

I know it's necessarily an answer to the question but it fixed the issue.

Comment: It is an answer because using migrations means that you must no do any changes to database manually.

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework stores the migrations that have been applied to the database in the `__MigrationHistory` table.  If you delete the row in this table representing a particular migration (the `MigrationId` column contains the name of the migration class), that migration will be reapplied the next time you do an `update-database`.

That said, this will cause the *entire* migration to be reapplied, not just the parts of it that happen to be missing in the database, including all table creations, drops, etc., etc., so use it with care if you haven't previously manually backed out the changes that that migration has put in place, as some of those operations can and will cause errors if the database objects already exist.